# What is a digital trainspotter

Tags: vocabulary

What does that mean when someone is described as a "digital trainspotter"?
Does that mean he is a digital enthusiast?

Thanks for response.

Comment: Can you give some context from the place you found this phrase?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with the same level of attention-to-detail (times, codes etc.) as a trainspotter.

Alternatively, a digital trainspotter could be said to be someone who points at trains before writing them down in their book.

Comment: Counts them on his fingers?